# Use static property of a c++ class in qml

Tags: c++, qt, class, qml

I have a c++ class like this:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString P1 READ getP1)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString P2 READ getP2)
public:
    inline explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

    inline static const QString P1 = "something1";
    inline static const QString P2 = "something2";

    Q_INVOKABLE inline static QString getP1() {return P1;}
    Q_INVOKABLE inline static QString getP2() {return P2;}
};
```

And I use it in other c++ classes and it's Ok. Now, I want to use P1 and P2 in my qml file too. So, I have in main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("com.MyClass", 1, 0, "MyClass");
```

And in my qml file:

```
import com.MyClass 1.0
.
.
.
console.log(MyClass.P1);
console.log(MyClass.getP2);
```

After running code, console show `undefined` for both of them! And `MyClass.getP2()` cause following error:

> TypeError: Property 'getP2' of object [object Object] is not a function

How can I use of P1 and P2 in qml?

**Solution:**

Based on @pooya13 answer, I put this in main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyClass>("com.MyClass", 1, 0, "MyClass",[](QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) -> QObject * {
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)

    MyClass *example = new MyClass();
    return example;
});
```

So, I could use `MyClass.P1` in qml file.

Comment: I'm not sure about accessing `static` methods but anyway, to access C++ method from QML you have to use [Q_INVOKABLE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html). I would use [singleton](https://qml.guide/singletons/) for such issue if you would as my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @folibis . I test it. I put Q_INVOKABLE  for class, constructor, property and method (One by one and together). but problem is persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As folibis pointed out, it seems that you are using `MyClass` as a QML singleton (`qmlRegisterSingletonInstance` or `qmlRegisterSingletonType`):

```
// Does not need to be instantiated in QML (`MyClass` refers to registered singleton object)
console.log(MyClass.prop)
console.log(MyClass.getProp())
```

whereas you are registering it as a regular type:

```
// Needs to be instantiated in QML (`MyClass` refers to registered type)
MyClass {
   Component.onCompleted: {
      console.log(prop)
      console.log(getProp())
   }
}
```